# Perform division with a loop

Tags: javascript

Someone asked me an interesting question today: "How would I use javascript to perform a division operation if javascript did not allow division with an operator." I wrote a function that uses the dividend and divisor as variables and then iterates over the dividend using the divisor variable as increments:

```
function divide(dividend,divisor){
    for(var i = 1; i <= dividend; i=i+divisor){
        console.log(i);
    }
}

divide(10,2);
```

Note that this is basic and will only work with positive integers.

This function will print a series of numbers. If each number were converted to an object then the sum of the objects could then be stored in a variable and that variable would be the solution. I have tried a number of solutions but each of them has produced an infinite loop. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: sure click on edit and then change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function divide(dividend,divisor){
    var result = 0;
    while(dividend >= divisor){
        dividend -= divisor;
        result++;
    }

    return result;
}

divide(10,2); // 5
```

See [this question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186421/how-to-divide-using-addition-or-subtraction) for some background regarding why this works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted to do.

```
function divide(dividend,divisor){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= dividend; i=i+divisor){
        count++;
       //console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(count);
    return count;
}

divide(10,2);
```

Comment: This will give incorrect results in some cases because the `i` is offset by `1`. So any time a number comes within `1` of being evenly divisible, the result will be off by 1. EX: `divide(11,2)`

Comment: That's true. I should have used: for(var i = 0; i < dividend; i=i+divisor)

Comment: @cookiemonster -- good point, but I think HelloWorld gets the idea.

Comment: I do but by all means I appreciate any knowledge, as I am learning javaScript on my own and am quickly developing a rabid interest

Answer (score 1):

Here's  version that deals with negative numbers, and a `0` dividend or divisor.

```
function divide(dividend,divisor) {
    if (dividend === 0 && divisor === 0)
        return NaN;

    if (dividend === 0)
        return 0;

    if (divisor === 0)
        return dividend > 0 ? Infinity : -Infinity;

    var neg = dividend * divisor < 0;

    dividend = Math.abs(dividend);
    divisor = Math.abs(divisor);

    for (var i = 0; dividend >= divisor; ++i)
        dividend -= divisor;

    return neg ? -i : i;
}
```

Comment: This is great too, I now have more than enough to extrapolate on my own. Thanks!